# Saving and loading sub classes in java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a way to save/load objects in Java, I have the class Item:

```
public class Item implements Serializable{
//Variables
private String name, desc;
private int price;

//Constructors
public Item(){
    this.name=this.desc="NA";
}
public Item(String name,String desc,int price){
    this.name=name;
    this.desc=desc;
    this.price=price;
}
public Item(String name){
    load(name);
}
public Item(Item i){
    this.name=i.name;
    this.desc=i.desc;
    this.price=i.price;
}

//Getters and Setters
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void save(){
    try{
        String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/JavaGame/Item/";
        new File(path).mkdirs();
        path+=this.name;
        path+=".dat";
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));
        outputStream.writeObject(this);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error saving: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
public void load(String name){
    try {
        String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/JavaGame/Item/";
        path+=name;
        path+=".dat";
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
        Item i = (Item) in.readObject();
        this.name=name;
        this.desc=i.desc;
        this.price=i.price;
        in.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error loading: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o==null||o.getClass()!=this.getClass())return false;
    Item i = (Item) o;
    return i.name.equals(this.name);
}
public String toString(){
    return new StringBuilder().append(this.name).append("\n").append(this.desc).toString();
}
public Item clone(){
    return new Item(this);
}
```

}

I want to create types of items, like usables and armor (for example). So I'll create a new Class called ArmorPiece, it has only a defense stat.
Let's imagine that the code is:

```
public class ArmorPiece extends Item{
    private int defense;

    public ArmrPiece(String name, int defense){
        setName(name);
        this.defense = defense;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "It's an armor piece";
    }
}
```

In this project I save all my Items info in the folder /JavaGame/Item/ and I want to save all Items in the same folder, when I run a test like the following it enters the else bracket, do you know how to make the "Item" turn into an "ArmorPiece"?

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    new ArmorPiece("boots",10).save();
    Item m = new Item("boots");//It will load the boots info into an Item
    if(m.getClass().getName().equals("ArmorPiece")){//It should enter the if since it is an ArmorPiece
        ArmorPiece ap=(ArmorPiece) m;
        System.out.println(ap);
    }
    else{//Enters this brackets, but it shouldn't
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have thought the methods to write to file should be external to the Objects you want to write

Comment: @ScaryWombat like having a class just to save/load?

Comment: Yes, then all Objects can be serialized to the same file

Comment: @ScaryWombat I'll try it now, wish me luck

Comment: You do realize that other forms of marshaling is better than Java serialization, if not anything, then purely in terms of performance? JSON is ubiquitous for a reason.

Comment: see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: why not use database and Hibernate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It may be inneficient, but I think you should use a way to load everything at once (In a HashMap for example) and then look for it there, you can even make it load the Map when you open the program. For example:

```
public class AllItems{
    Map<String,Item> allItems;

    public AllItems(){
        allItems = new HashMap<String,Item>();
        //Load all items here(You can save them all in one file)
    }

    public Item getItem(String name){
        return allItems.get(name);//You need to make this always work, so you should check if the item exists first.
    }
}
```

This is just an example, but you could try to do it this way.

Comment: I understanded the logic, and it probably works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you create `Item` class. You can't change class of object after creation. I suggest you to make your `load` method static and return `i` from it.